# How do you span columns in C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, grid

How do you span columns in C#?
In silverlight, suppose you have a grid, and this grid is in 3 columns.
and you want to add a UserControl to this grid but you want it to span all three
columns.  How would that C# code look like?

```
 Grid1.Children.Add(UserControl01);
```

But then what?

```
Grid1.Children.ElementAt(1).SetValue(Grid.SetRowSpan, 2);
```

??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
Grid1.Children.Add(UserControl01);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(UserControl01, 3);
```

MSDN Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumnspan.aspx

Comment: Grid1.Children.Add(UserControl01);

Grid.SetColumnSpan(UserControl01, 3);